# Placeholder text misaligned in UITextField of UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customize UISearchBar's font through appearance proxy. It works, but somehow, the placeholder text is not centered vertically. I tried to set the vertical alignment property; the placeholder text would get centred but text entered would be slightly below the center line... Is there any way to fix this?

**Edit: Code I used to add custom font:**

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil]
                                setFont: [UIFont customFontWithSize: 17]];
```

[image: placeholder text]

[image: normal text]

Comment: how are you setting the placeholder???

Comment: show the code you're using to setup the appearance and the placeholder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526047/uisearchbar-display-bug-text-too-far-left-overlapping-the-magnifying-glass-ico

Comment: searchBar.placeholder = @"ENTER AN ADDRESS AND AS YOU WANT"; use with

Comment: @iPatel Hmm.. I don't think I override any UITextfield draw methods.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this happens to me, it is usually caused by some modification to `UIAppearance` not blending well with `UISearchBar`. Look at any previous hacks you may have made and perhaps try commenting them out one at a time.

In my particular case it was actually a modification to `NSForegroundColor` in a text attribute, so this misalignment may be unrelated to your font change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set alignment of textField inside the searchBar.
Get textField from subviews of UISearch bar and simply set its alignment to center.Try sample code below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    for (UITextField *txt in _searchbar.subviews) {
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [txt setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        }
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

here _searchbar is outlet of UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    for (UITextField *txt in search.subviews) {
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            txt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17];
            txt.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Try this code once.